# resampling or groupby aggregation based on another series or PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I have a time series (typically 15min to 1 day). I would like to aggregate this series (sums, means) over coarser periods provided by either a PeriodIndex or another time series built on a PeriodIndex.

I've given an example below -- the last line is the one that expresses my intent but does not work (the argument to resample isn't right). Note that even though my example uses regular periods, which would be amenable to simple calls to resample() with some code to work out the base/offset based on my input series, I can't count on that regularity in my real application, and I need it to work for an irregular but sequential period index.

```
ndx=pd.date_range(start="2005-01-01",freq="D",periods=40)
df0 = pd.DataFrame({"data":np.arange(40)},index=ndx)
periods = pd.period_range(start="2005-01-03",freq="W",periods=5)
df1 = df0.resample(periods).mean()  # Does not work
```

Comment: What is the problem with df0.resample('W').mean()

Comment: See the last sentence. The solution `df0.resample('W').mean()` assumes a regular, known period.  I can't count on this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at documentation of *resample*.
The first argument is **rule** - *DateOffset*, *Timedelta* or *str*
- the new frequency of your data.

You attempted to pass a *PeriodRange*, so don't be surprised that *Pandas*
complains about this discrepancy.

Note that *resample* allows only grouping on "regular" periods.
A point to note is also that *resample* generates a "continuous sequence"
of resampling periods and for any such period which doesn't contain
any source rows, an **empty** group is created
(I suppose you don't want this).

So it looks like, you actually wanted to do something like **grouping**
rows by "irregular periods" and count mean values for each such period.

To do it, proceed as follows:

**Stage 1**: Define "border dates"

```
per = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([ '2005-01-01', '2005-01-04', '2005-01-09',
    '2005-01-16', '2005-02-01', '2005-02-14'], name='per'))
```

The meaning is:

- The first period: [2005-01-01, 2005-01-03].
- The second period: [2005-01-04, 2005-01-08], and so on.
- The last period: [2005-02-01, 2005-02-13].

**Stage 2**: Create a DataFrame with *from* / *to* dates

```
dfPer = pd.DataFrame({'dFrom': per, 'dTo': per.shift(-1)\
    - pd.DateOffset(1)}).dropna()
```

The result is:

```
       dFrom        dTo
0 2005-01-01 2005-01-03
1 2005-01-04 2005-01-08
2 2005-01-09 2005-01-15
3 2005-01-16 2005-01-31
4 2005-02-01 2005-02-13
```

**Stage 3**: Compute the result and save it in *meanVal* column in *dfPer*

```
dfPer['meanVal'] = dfPer.apply(
    lambda row: df0[row.dFrom:row.dTo].data.mean(), axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
       dFrom        dTo  meanVal
0 2005-01-01 2005-01-03      1.0
1 2005-01-04 2005-01-08      5.0
2 2005-01-09 2005-01-15     11.0
3 2005-01-16 2005-01-31     22.5
4 2005-02-01 2005-02-13     35.0
```

As you can notice, I didn't actually call any *groupby*, but
`df0[row.dFrom:row.dTo]` provides just the same functionality.
It selects rows from *df0* with index values between both dates
(inclusive).

To check validity, if you want to compare the above results with
source values in each "group", run:

```
dfPer.apply(lambda row: df0[row.dFrom:row.dTo].data.values, axis=1)
```

Comment: I was not surprised that it didn't work. Please also see response to WeNYoBen. I tried to hint that I understood the simplicity if the frequency is regular and known. Perhaps I need to rewrite it with weird periods to force the issue?

Comment: The groupby solution (your step 2) hints at what I was after with this question. If you were to describe how to do that using my example setup it would probably be a good answer.